# Solving the indefinite integral $\int\frac{dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}$ by conjugates

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate

> $$\int\frac{dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}$$

For one method - the first step to take would be to multiply by conjugate

$$\int\frac{(e^x)^2}{(e^x)^2}\frac{dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}$$

My question is: Why would the conjugate of $(e^x + e^{-x})^2$ be? $\dfrac{(e^x)^2}{(e^x)^2}$?

*Taken from my professor.*

Comment: please use Latex

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Who said $(e^x)^2/(e^x)^2$ was the "**conjugate**" of $(e^x+e^{-x})^2$? Did anyone actually say that, or do you assume that since we multiplied top and bottom by something it must be the "conjugate" as that's the process you're used to doing?

Comment: @anon Please don't tell me you can multiply arbitrary values onto a rational function. \ And a conjugate in my definition if the rational expression is (x + 1) is (x - 1)

Comment: $\frac{ab}{ac}=\frac{b}{c}$ is always true (barring $a,c=0$). The only reason we pick $a$ to be the conjugate of $c$ (where applicable) is because it helps us simplify the fraction in a useful way in those circumstances. If there is no conjugate, there can easily be other things we multiply by that help us solve our problems.

Answer (score 2):

> $e^{2x}$ is **Not** conjugate of $(e^x + e^{-x})^2$

$$I=\int\frac{\,\mathrm dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}=\int\frac{\,\mathrm dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}=\int\frac{e^{2x}\,\mathrm dx}{(e^{2x} +1)^2}$$

Now making an *obvious* substitution
$$e^{2x}+1=t\iff 2e^{2x}\,\mathrm dx=\,\mathrm dt$$

$$I=\int\frac{\,\mathrm dt}{2t^2}=-\frac{1}{2t}+c=-\frac{1}{2e^{2x}+2}+c$$

> $$\large\int\frac{\,\mathrm dx}{(e^x + e^{-x})^2}=-\frac{1}{2e^{2x}+2}+c$$